# SharePoint 2010 - Approval task opens in client for one user and in the browser for another user

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow-settings

Approval task have multiple approvers. When one user clicks on 'open this task' button received in the email, the task opens in the client. Another user when clicks on 'open this task' button in the email, the task opens in the browser. how can i fix it to open the task in the client?

Thank you
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

What’s the version of Outlook that users use?

If we use Outlook 2016, it’s by default that the task opens in the browser since the Microsoft InfoPath E-Mail Forms function is no longer in Outlook 2016.
We can use Outlook 2010 or Outlook 2013 to open this task in the client.

[Here is the similar post for your reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9dae1c54-7e6c-4219-aa60-1c44a5f2b4b6/outlook-2016sharepoint-2013-open-this-task-button?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: Thanks Fiona, that was one of the first things I checked. User is on Office 2010.